# node.js npm install fs error

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx:/var/www/html$ npm install fs
npm WARN package.json crypto@0.0.3 crypto is also the name of a node core module.
npm WARN package.json filesystem@1.0.1 No description
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 http is also the name of a node core module.
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json http@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json js@0.1.0 No repository field.

npm WARN package.json querystring@0.2.0 querystring is also the name of a node core module.
    npm WARN package.json url@0.10.1 url is also the name of a node core module.
    npm WARN package.json util@0.10.3 util is also the name of a node core module.
    npm ERR! 404 Not Found
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404 'fs' is not in the npm registry.
    npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
    npm ERR! 404 
    npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
    npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
```

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
    npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "fs"
    npm ERR! cwd /var/www/html
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
    npm ERR! code E404
    npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
    npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: 'npm-debug.log' }

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

```
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "fs"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/html
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I 'm typed "npm install fs" ,but see the this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821698/npm-install-error-issue

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're getting error because fs module is part of node's core modules.  You don't need to install.  http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: It doesn't seem like I can import them or require them. I get `Error: Can't resolve 'fs'.` for either one of these `import { fs } from "fs";` or `const fs = require('fs');`

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to install nodejs internal modules, but you can update them.
fs is a internal node js module!