# Cannot find module "fs". Using simple-json-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, node-modules, fs, angular2-components

I'm try to use `simple-json-loader`. I install this from npm and write following function:

```
onclickExport() {
    var loader = require('simple-json-loader');
    var json = loader.JSONLoader.loadFromFile('wwwroot/dist/data/files.json');
}
```

Еverything seems simple, but when I run build in webback i see following error:

> ERROR in ./~/simple-json-loader/index.js
>       Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in D:\GitRepo\Magazine\Magazine.Web\node_modules\simple-json-loader
>        @ ./~/simple-json-loader/index.js

Npm package is in the node_modules by valid path. I see it there. 
Also In debugging of this function i see analogous error.
Is any ideas why it is not work?

Comment: So it's a server-side package, which won't work client-side (in a browser) unless you're using something like [`BrowserFS`](https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is that the module `simple-json-loader` is reliant on the built-in Node module `fs`. `fs` is a module that performs various file-loading and file system tasks.

Since it looks like you're building in Angular2, which is a front-end (client-side) Javascript framework, this may be an environment issue.

It's not possible for the client-side browser environment to interpret and run some Node modules like `fs` that are built to be run in a server-side Node environment. [(more here)](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-JavaScript-and-Node-js/answer/Corey-Butler?share=7a58545f)

The solution is to run the `simple-json-loader` module server-side in a Node environment or to find a package which offers the same functionality but written for the browser.

It's discussed in this question...
[Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358748/module-not-found-error-cannot-resolve-module-fs/48359480)

And this question...
[Use fs module in React.js,node.js, webpack, babel,express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983275/use-fs-module-in-react-js-node-js-webpack-babel-express)

Comment: This is also an interesting thread about fs functionality for the browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467858/manipulating-the-local-file-system-with-browser-based-javascript-and-node

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify `target` in webpack config:

```js
target: 'node'
```

And this will work only on server side as node.js program.