# Manipulating the local file system with browser-based JavaScript and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a project that needs to allow users to interact with the file system from a browser. I have a lot of experience writing client-side JavaScript, and I have a lot of experience writing Node scripts for things like web scraping, data analysis, and file system work. But this project will let users change things in the browser, and then save that data locally (and, eventually, to a web server) – and I have no experience with this.

I've installed [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) and [browserify-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) to use Node's fs module in the browser, and used the example from the browserify-fs README to create a directory, write a file to it, and then read that file:

```
var fs = require('browserify-fs');

fs.mkdir("/home", function(err){
    if (err) throw err;

    fs.writeFile("/home/hello-world.txt", "Hello world!", function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        fs.readFile("/home/hello-world.txt", "utf-8", function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This "works" in the sense that it logs "Hello world!" in the console. But as far as I can tell, it does not create a directory or save a file locally. I have some vague sense that it is saving these things temporarily in the browser, and that they are deleted when I navigate away. But I want to actually create a directory and save a file in it locally. Can I do that with JavaScript alone? Is there a good tutorial on how to "close the loop" between browser-based JavaScript and Node?

#### Update

I've accepted T.J. Crowder's response – ExpressJS does, indeed, make client-server communication in JavaScript relatively simple. What I'm doing now is, I'm saving the user's entries to a global JSON object. When the user clicks a "save" button, I update the value of a hidden `<input>` element in a `<form>` element with the stringified JSON. Then I submit the form, and Express's `app.post()` plus the module [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) give me everything in `req.body`. Then I can perform normal Node file system operations.

Comment: Imagine if JavaScript could access the file system. Anybody could create a website that wreaks havoc on the computer of anybody that simply visits it. If you want to store things locally, use `localStorage`.

Comment: Looking at `browserify-fs`, it's not at all what you want...

Comment: Unfortunately the only file-access you have with Browser based javascript is using an INPUT tag with type file,  that asks the user what file.  local-storage / IndexedDb etc, can be used for storing data though.  If you want more control you can create an application with embeded webkit / node system.  It's what things like Atom.io use etc.  Try-> https://electron.atom.io/

Comment: Can we see how you actually managed to do it? Otherwise the "Update" effectively kills the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Naturally, browser-hosted JavaScript cannot access the file system of the user's machine (at present; someday, some kind of sandboxed access may happen — the [last attempt](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) failed, but that doesn't mean the next one has to — [the next attempt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) is in Chromium browsers now).

So to do this, you'll need two pieces:

1. A browser piece, which does the UI with the user.
2. A Node piece, which runs on the user's machine (and thus can access the file system) and which the browser piece uses to do the actual file operations.

Probably the easiest way for the pieces to interact would be HTTP, which you can trivially support using [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com).

So for instance, if the user wants to delete a file:

1. User clicks something to say "delete this file"
2. Browser JavaScript sends the command to the Node process over HTTP via ajax
3. Node process does the deletion and reports success/failure
4. Browser JavaScript displays the result

Comment: ExpressJS is doing the trick perfectly. Thank you! By the way, a good book for learning the basics is O'Reilly's Web Development with Node and Express by Todd Brown.

Comment: Several browsers now support the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), which can be used to edit local files.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Yes, Google is trying again. :-) (Third time's a charm!) But it's only them for now: The File System Access API is only in Chromium-based browsers, not Firefox or Safari.  So really, one browser with multiple faces (and Brave, which is otherwise Chromium-based, [does not support it](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/11407) because "the privacy / security model is extemely not fleshed out...).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this purely in Javascript. Javascript running on browsers does not have enough permission yet (there have been proposals) due to security reasons.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API/Introduction#restrictions

> Because the file system is sandboxed, a web app cannot access another app's files. You also cannot read or write files to an arbitrary folder (for example, My Pictures and My Documents) on the user's hard drive.

Comment: *"You cannot do this purely in Javascript."* Sure you can.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would love to know how to access filesystem with pure javascript (browser side only). If you have a lib name, it would be great

Comment: That's not what you said. You said *"You cannot do this purely in Javascript."* Yes, you can -- with Node (or any of several other non-browser JavaScript environments), not in the browser. The OP even *mentions* Node in the question.

Comment: The OP also mentions that the result is eventually uploaded to a server, which suggests he's looking for a way to do this with a pure in-browser client, as far as I can see.

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to do this with a pure in-browser client. T.J. Crowder's response was very helpful.