# Browser returns fake path when we choose file in javascript

Tags: javascript

Browsers won't allow  to access and explore the file system of the client computers using javascript. Some browsers will  return  fake path to the file.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guide of how to ask questions.

Comment: Yes, you have accurately described the browser behavior. Do you have a question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manipulating the local file system with browser-based JavaScript and Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467858/manipulating-the-local-file-system-with-browser-based-javascript-and-node)