# How to use 'fs' module in React project correctly now (both JavaScript and TypeScript Version)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, fs

I have used `import * as fs from 'fs';`, `import fs from 'fs';`, `import { readFile } from 'fs';`, `const fs = require('fs');` & `const fs = (window).require('fs');`, but none of them runs correctly.

The application created by `create-react-app`, one is JavaScript Version another one is TypeScript Version. I want know how to solve this issue, and the reason of its cause.

1. When using `import * as fs from 'fs';` & `import fs from 'fs'`, it shows `TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function`.
2. When using `import { readFile } from 'fs';`, it shows `Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`.
3. When using `const fs = (window).require('fs');`, it shows `window.require is not a function`.
4. When using `const fs = require('fs');`, it shows `fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.readFile is not a function`.

Whether is the matter of config file of project or tsconfig? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `fs` is a node package.. React is for the web. What do you require `fs` for?

Comment: I want to use fs to execute file and show its content on the browser. Actually, I do not know whether this idea is practicable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs` is a node server side module, and normally browser javascript cannot access the file system. But you could try and set up a backend server using [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) to handle requests and then use `fs` on your node server to handle file system functions.

Read more about it in :

- [Github create-react-app Issues](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3074)
- [stackoverflow manipulating files via browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467858/manipulating-the-local-file-system-with-browser-based-javascript-and-node)