# Converting CSV to JSON with headers

Tags: javascript, json, csv, type-conversion

Hi I have been attempting to convert a CSV to a JSON using csvtojson module. I have been trying to follow the steps outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831250/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-node-js) but I am encountering an unusual error saying `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fs'`

I am beginning by importing the module

```
import csv from "csvtojson";
```

I couldn't find any documentation on the [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) docs page stating that I should install and import a module fs (although I have attempted to do this).

The function I am running looks like this:

```
handleFiles = () => {
    let newfile = this.refs.file.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();

    csv({
        ignoreEmpty: true,
        headers: ["Year", "Month", "Name"]
    })
    .fromFile(newfile.name)
    .then((jsonObj) => {
        console.log(jsonObj);
    })
}
```

the input looks like this:

```
<input ref="file" type="file" onChange={this.handleFiles} filetypes={'.csv'}>
</input>
```

The only issue I can see is possibly from this line `.fromFile(newfile.name)`

The docs state to use `.fromFile(<path to csv file>)` but the path is not always known.  Instead I am using the file name.  Nevertheless the error I am getting doesn't seem to be related to this.

Comment: Are you writing a Node application?

Comment: no this is within a react component.

Comment: Sorry I linked the wrong answer, this is the right one, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48856076/2218253 It is likely it wont work since that is a node module and you are using React.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48359480/2218253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fs'

**Answer**

You are trying to use a library that has a Node server side library as a dependency. When the library runs it tries to use methods from the library `fs` which is used server side and is not used in React.js.