# Should core Node modules be listed in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

My code uses core Node modules such as `fs` and `path`. Is there any reason to include them in `package.json` (`npm i fs path`)? The [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path) for npm path says "This is an exact copy of the NodeJS ’path’ module published to the NPM registry." Why do these packages have around a million downloads a week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any reason to include them in `package.json` (`npm i fs path`)?

**No**. These packages have been bundled as part of every major Node release since its inception. They do not need to be installed separately or included in your `package.json` file.

---

> Why do these packages have around a million downloads a week?

I suppose you could really only speculate, but it's likely that a nonzero number of newcomers aren't aware these modules are available as part of the core of Node and are running `npm install fs`, etc. following the same idea as some of the documentation or tutorials they're reviewing.

It's prudent to ensure that not only if one does include these modules that they work as intended, but to also prevent unscrupulous actors from namesquatting and enabling [dependency confusion vulnerabilities](https://medium.com/@alex.birsan/dependency-confusion-4a5d60fec610). The [npm page for the `fs` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) even states explicitly why they've elected to publish it (emphasis mine):

> This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied by another package. **To avoid malicious use**, npm is hanging on to the package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you want it.

Comment: That's what I figured, someone was telling me I needed to and I thought that was silly for the reasons you list. I wondered if maybe there was a way to indicate you use those core modules in case they were ever migrated from core and there would be a fallback npm package.

Comment: In my personal view, the likelihood of these modules being migrated out of the core is so miniscule it doesn't make sense to even spend time thinking about how you might mitigate such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24596500/2658167), you don't need install it, so you don't need specify it in `package.json`. Also `fs`, `path` are Node.js core modules.

Sorry for my bad english. Have a nice day!